# who to limit number of li in wp_nav_menu

Tags: menus

need help regarding wordpress navigation

i am using

```
 if ( has_nav_menu( 'main_nav' ) ) {
   wp_nav_menu( array('menu' => 'guest menu' )); 
 }
```

from back end if i keep the menu empty(do not any page/category to menu) it displays all the pages in menu on front end.

i want it it to display nothing or by default only one menu item
(only one `<li`>) if the menu in back end is empty.

can i limit `wp_nav_menu()` to display only one `<li>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [Function Reference/wp nav menu](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nav_menu)

```
if ( has_nav_menu( 'main_nav' ) ) {
    wp_nav_menu( array('menu' => 'guest menu', 'fallback_cb' => false )); 
}
```

Comment: thanks i tried this but didn't worked yesterday, now it works fine. now just one thing more. that i want only one item in front end menu even if there are many in back end

Comment: Write a function and use it as `'fallback_cb'` in `wp_nav_menu`. There is no a lot of information or examples in your question to say more.